# Ordered field with Monotone Convergence Property has Nested Interval Property

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Prove that an ordered field (not necessarily assumed complete) with the Monotone Convergence Property has the Nested Interval Property. *There are many proofs of this on this site and elsewhere; this question is to verify or critique* my *proof.*

Let $(a_n), (b_n)$ be sequences in the field such that for all $n$, for all $m < n$, $a_n \leq b_n, a_n \geq a_m, b_n \leq b_m$; that is, of nested intervals.

By the ordered field axioms, $(a_n)$ is bounded by $b_1$ and monotonically increasing; thus, it converges.  Similarly, $(b_n)$ converges. We need to show that $\lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$.

Since the individual limits are each defined, $\lim b_n - \lim a_n = \lim \,(b_n-a_n) =: \ell.$  Since $b_n \geq a_n$ for all $n$, then $\ell \geq 0$.  For if $\ell < 0$, we'd have a contradiction, because $|(b_n - a_n) - \ell| > |\ell/2|$ for all $n$.

Thus, $\lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$, and the closed interval $[\lim a_n, \lim b_n]$ is non-empty. QED.

Please verify or critique this proof (and exposition).  Is the part about $\ell$ clear? My goal was to be rigorous, succinct, and clear.

---

To address Abhijeet Vats' comment:

We also need to show that $[\lim a_n, \lim b_n]$ is *nested* in the other intervals; that is, that $a_n \leq \lim a_n$ for all $n$, and similarly for $b_n$. That is, it's not enough to demonstrate the existence of *some* non-empty interval; we need to show it is contained within all the previous ones.

**Proof:** A bounded monotonically increasing sequence converges to a limit greater or equal to all it's elements.  For if there existed $a_k > \lim a_n$, then no subsequent element could be less than $a_k - \lim a_n > 0$ above $a_n$.

Thus, $a_n \leq \lim a_n$ for all $n$.  Similarly, $b_n \geq \lim b_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: I think you need to also show that $[\lim a_n, \lim b_n] \subseteq \bigcap [a_n,b_n]$. But otherwise, your proof seems fine.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats Thanks! Can you check my update?